# routing with angular js and expressjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am trying to start a project with express and angularjs. I was following [this](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/backend-integration-with-node-express/implementing-client-side-routing.html) guide.
On first go i.e running localhost:3000, I am loading my index.jade file inside views directory successfully.
index.jade

```
extends layout

block content
    div
        ng-view

    include footerjs
```

footerjs.jade

```
script(src="/javascripts/angular.min.js")
script(src="/javascripts/angular-route.js")
script(src="/javascripts/angular-resource.js")
script(src="/javascripts/app.js")
script(src="/javascripts/task.js")
```

views directory has a folder called partials. inside this folder I have added two templates. "task.jade" and "landing.jade".

my app.js

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute', 'taskApp', "ngResource", 'ui.router' ]);

mainApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',function(routeProvider, locationProvider) {
    locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/landing',
            controller: 'taskController'
        }).
        when('/task', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/task',
            controller: 'taskController'
        }).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

and I have made an express route as:

```
router.get('/partials/:urlName', function(req, res) {
    res.render('partials/'+req.params.urlName);
});
```

I am not able to route any partials. I am stuck at my layout at initial and an error 404 on trying to route /task. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the file extension in templateUrl:

```
routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/landing.jade',
            controller: 'taskController'
        }).
        when('/task', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/task.jade',
            controller: 'taskController'
        }).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
```